# 6502 ASM linker calculates wrong jump offset

Tags: assembly, 6502, ca65, apple-ii

It seems to me that 6502's ASM linker screws the logical sequence of my code that way so I can't explain why.
At the lines marked with ( <-- O) the address pointer becoming offset by 2 bytes. So it jumps at the line marked with ( <-- 1). Then, every data pointer at the lines marked with ( <-- S) has starting address offset in 4 bytes. As the result, part of a message is not being displayed.

Please share with me your thoughts of what I possibly doing wrong here.

- target system: apple 2c

main.asm

```
.org $2000

.macro  asc Arg
        .repeat .strlen(Arg), I
        .byte   .strat(Arg, I) | $80
        .endrep
.endmacro

.define asc2(Arg)  asc Arg

.macro  ascz Arg
        .repeat .strlen(Arg), I
        .byte   .strat(Arg, I) | $80
        .endrep
        .byte   $00
.endmacro

.macro  asccr Arg
        .repeat .strlen(Arg), I
        .byte   .strat(Arg, I) | $80
        .endrep
        .byte   $8d
.endmacro

    COUT     = $FDED
    CHR_CR = $8D
    PTR = $06
    VTAB    = $FC22
    CH  = $24
    CV  = $25

    cld
    ldx #$FF
    txs
    lda #$69
    sta $03F2
    lda #$ff
    sta $03F3
    eor #$a5
    sta $03F4
    jsr $FC58
    jsr $FE84
    jsr $FE89
    jsr $FE93

    lda $BF98
    and #$A8
    cmp #$A8
    bcs @ErrEnvMachine
    clc
    lda #$02
    bit $BF98
    beq @ErrEnv80Col

@ErrEnvMachine:
    lda #$01
    jmp ERRHNDLR
@ErrEnv80Col:
    lda #$02
    jmp ERRHNDLR

ERRHNDLR:
    cmp #$01
    beq @ErrEnvMachine
    cmp #$02
    beq @ErrEnv80Col
    bne @ErrGeneric

@ErrEnvMachine:
    lda #<MErrEnvM
    sta PTR
    lda #>MErrEnvM
    sta PTR+1
    beq PrintErrMsg

@ErrEnv80Col:
    lda #<MErr80Col
    sta PTR
    lda #>MErr80Col
    sta PTR+1
    beq PrintErrMsg

@ErrGeneric:
    lda #<MErrgen
    sta PTR
    lda #>MErrgen
    sta PTR+1
PrintErrMsg:
    ldx #$0
    ldy #$17
    jsr GOTOXY
    ldy #$00
:   lda (PTR),y
    beq :+
    jsr COUT
    iny
    bne :-
:   jmp EXIT

GOTOXY:
    stx CH
    sty CV
    jsr VTAB
    rts

EXIT:
    dec $03F4
    jsr  $BF00
    .byte   $65
    .word   PARMTABLE

PARMTABLE:
    .byte   $04
    .byte   $00
    .word   $0000
    .byte   $00
    .word   $0000

MErrEnvM:
    ascz "PROG WON'T RUN"

MErr80Col:
    ascz "PROG REQUIRES 80-COL MODE"

MErrgen:
    ascz "AN ERROR OCCURRED"
```

**[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uvCVI.png)***

disk image [PROG.po.zip](https://github.com/cc65/cc65/files/13064883/PROG.po.zip)

Thanks!

**PS:**
This error doesn't depend on the "cheap"/unnamed labels, the logic sequence or the compiler.

---

**UPDATE #1:**

build.sh

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash

ca65 --cpu 6502 -t apple2 -l main.lst main.asm -o main.o
ld65 -o PROG -C main.cfg -m main.map main.o

...
exit 0
```

main.cfg

```
SYMBOLS {
    __FILETYPE__: type = weak, value = $00FF; # ProDOS file type (SYS)
    __STACKSIZE__: type = weak, value = $0800; # 2k stack
}
MEMORY {
    RAM:    file = %O, define = yes, start = $2000,         size = $BF00 - $2000,         fill=yes;
    BSS:    file = "",               start = __RAM_LAST__,  size = $BF00 - __RAM_LAST__;
}
SEGMENTS {
    CODE:     load = RAM,   type = ro;
    RODATA:   load = RAM,   type = ro;
    BSS:      load = RAM,   type = bss;
}
```

---

**UPDATE #2:**

Disassembled as:

```bash
da65 --cpu 6502 --start-addr=$2000 -o PROG.dasm PROG
```

Output:

```
; da65 V2.18 - N/A
; Created:    2023-10-22 17:45:36
; Input file: PROG
; Page:       1


        .setcpu "6502"

L0004           := $0004
L203A           := $203A
L2076           := $2076
L207E           := $207E
        cld
        ldx     #$FF
        txs
        lda     #$69
        sta     $03F2
        lda     #$FF
        sta     $03F3
        eor     #$A5
        sta     $03F4
        jsr     LFC58
        jsr     LFE84
        jsr     LFE89
        jsr     LFE93
        lda     LBF98
        and     #$A8
        cmp     #$A8
        bcs     L6130
        clc
        lda     #$02
        bit     LBF98
        beq     L6135
L6130:  lda     #$01
        jmp     L203A

L6135:  lda     #$02
        jmp     L203A

        cmp     #$01
        beq     L6144
        cmp     #$02
        beq     L614E
        bne     L6158
L6144:  lda     #$8E
        sta     $06
        lda     #$20
        sta     $07
        beq     L6160
L614E:  lda     #$9D
        sta     $06
        lda     #$20
        sta     $07
        beq     L6160
L6158:  lda     #$B7
        .byte   $85
L615B:  asl     $A9
        jsr     $0785
L6160:  ldx     #$00
L6162:  ldy     #$17
        jsr     L2076
        ldy     #$00
L6169:  lda     ($06),y
        beq     L6173
        jsr     LFDED
        iny
L6171:  bne     L6169
L6173:  jmp     L207E

        stx     $24
        sty     $25
        jsr     LFC22
        rts

        dec     $03F4
        jsr     LBF00
        adc     $87
        jsr     L0004
        brk
        brk
        brk
        brk
        brk
        bne     L6162
        .byte   $CF
        .byte   $C7
        ldy     #$D7
        .byte   $CF
        dec     LD4A7
        ldy     #$D2
        cmp     $CE,x
        brk
        bne     L6171
        .byte   $CF
        .byte   $C7
        ldy     #$D2
        cmp     $D1
        cmp     $C9,x
        .byte   $D2
        cmp     $D3
        ldy     #$B8
        bcs     L615B
        .byte   $C3
        .byte   $CF
        cpy     LCDA0
        .byte   $CF
        cpy     $C5
        brk
        cmp     ($CE,x)
        ldy     #$C5
        .byte   $D2
        .byte   $D2
        .byte   $CF
        .byte   $D2
        ldy     #$CF
        .byte   $C3
        .byte   $C3
        cmp     $D2,x
        .byte   $D2
        cmp     $C4
        ...
        brk
```

---

**UPDATE #3:**

```bash
java -jar acx-1.8.0.jar create -d PROG.po --prodos-order --name=PROG --format=ProDOS_2_4_2.dsk --prodos --size=140kb
java -jar acx-1.8.0.jar import --dos PROG --disk=PROG.po --name=PROG.SYSTEM -t=sys --aux=8192
java -jar acx-1.8.0.jar unlock -d PROG.po BASIC.SYSTEM
java -jar acx-1.8.0.jar del -d PROG.po BASIC.SYSTEM
java -jar acx-1.8.0.jar lock -d PROG.po PROG.SYSTEM
```

Comment: That sounds like you did not load it at the address it was assembled (linked) for.

Comment: Thanks @Jester, but this is the first thing I thought of and this is not the reason. It assembles and starts at $2000. I've just double checked that. (example code updated)

Comment: Can you post disassembly (or a listing)?

Comment: The SYS disassembly differs from the listing here. The first byte (CLD) is missing. Please show the commands you're using to assemble the binary and put it into a disk image. Also, if there's a CA65 issue, could you please link to it? You might benefit from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58787146/313445).

Comment: @NickWestgate, please see **UPDATE #1**.

Comment: @Jester, please see **UPDATE #2**.

Comment: Disassembly seems correct (expected addresses, but in the meantime I assembled your file locally and indeed `ERRHNDLR` is at `203A`).

Comment: @Jester correct. There must be the simple explanation to this issue since all the compilers I've tried giving the same result. (ca65, dasm, mos (https://github.com/datatrash/mos))

Comment: As Nick says, the file in the image is missing leading bytes (I think 4, not just the `CLD`). How do you create the image from the program?

Comment: Yes probably, I am on it right now.

Comment: @Jester, sorry for the delay. Please have a look at **UPDATE #3** block.

Comment: The program is clearly missing a few lines at the very beginning, these are: 
**cld,
    ldx #$FF,
    txs** 
why could that happen?

Comment: @Sergio: From the AC docs: "-dos <imagename> <filename> <type> put stdin with DOS header in filename on image, **using file type and address from header**." There's the 4 bytes it's stealing. Not sure how to do that correctly with ACX. (Possibly a bug.)

Comment: Thanks Nick for pointing out the problem. I've read that too but never thought it could cause a problem like I came with. I've checked acx's code and was convinced it automatically adds these 4 bytes as a header. it's insane that in 21st century someone can spend so much time on finding a silly issue. =) my stack been actually overflowed

Comment: Glad to help (just a little bit). If you can work out the correct syntax please answer your own question below. You could file an issue with AC on GitHub or ask for help in the [comp.sys.apple2 UseNet group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/comp.sys.apple2).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alright. There are few points to mention, based on [this discussion](https://github.com/AppleCommander/AppleCommander/issues/122) on GitHub.

1. I managed to learn how to properly create and manage disk images created for Apple II' computers. =)
2. The current version of AppleCommander (ACX) needs to be upgraded to be able to properly import binary files. Hopefully, in version 1.9 we'll be able to use the full-functional import feature.

---

Many thanks to all who helped in finding the answers.

Comment: Thanks for following through with logging the AC issue. Maybe have a look at [Cadius](https://github.com/mach-kernel/cadius) from the other answer I referred to. It has some *nix support IIRC.

Comment: Looks good! Thanks for the tip, Nick!